# Warning: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray<NSString *> * _Nullable'

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray

I'm trying to figure out how to get around this warning. I'm populating a UITableView with the contents of the docs directory. The code executes fine but I need to clean up this warning.

```
@implementation ViewSavedFiles
{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}
@synthesize myFileName;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    tableData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:NULL];

}
```

It's warning me: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *' from 'NSArray * _Nullable'

If I change NSMutableArray to NSArray I get ARC Semantic Issue errors later in:

```
[tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and

```
[tableData insertObject:objectToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

it tells me: 
No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

docPath jas to be a string and tableData has to be some sort of an array so I'm confused.
 Thanks!!

Comment: Unrelated but why do you have the `@synthesize` line? That hasn't been needed for many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` returns immutable `NSArray`. You have to make a `mutableCopy`

```
tableData = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager]  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:NULL] mutableCopy];
```

or use an initializer

```
NSArray *fileNames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]  contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docPath error:NULL];
tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: fileNames];
```

Comment: Thanks!! mutableCopy fixed it perfectly.